# Login using entity provider and JWT

Tags: authentication, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am trying to implement the JWT authentication in an Api-platform project follow the instructions written in the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt). it works if I use the memory provider but when I am trying to configure it with the entity provider I always get the response 401 bad credentials.

If I change the provider and I use "in_memory" instead of "my_own_provider" it works. I have some fixtures with some users and I check the database and it contains the rows of the users correctly.

This is my security.yml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
#    encoders:
#        App\Entity\User: bcrypt

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: plaintext
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:
                        password: user-test
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    admin:
                        password: admin-test
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
        my_own_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
                # if you're using multiple entity managers
                # manager_name: customer
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: my_own_provider
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api_documentation:
            pattern:   ^/api/documentation
            anonymous: ~
            provider: my_own_provider

        api:
            pattern:   ^/
            stateless: true
            provider: my_own_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator



    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/documentation, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_API: [ROLE_USER]
```

This is my entity class:

```
<?php

// src/Entity/User.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=254, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId( $id )
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail( $email )
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $isActive
     */
    public function setIsActive( $isActive )
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }




    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

I find that some people asked the same question but no work for me.

[1 Example](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/34) It is really similar to my issue but I think that server configuration is not my problem because using in_memory it works. I also try the last solution json_login instead form_login and I have an error.

[2 Example](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/97) Here is Unauthorized but my problem is that I am not able to get the token.

I also try with bcrypt instead of plaintext but without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem. In memory works perfectly. Did you resolve it? 
I tried a few things that i saw in google but i couldn't make it work. One of those things was to add to the virtual host some directives for apache. Did you try that? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I used a custom query to load a user, because `jwt` doesn't recognize which property to target to in the user provider.
You can follow this [tutorial of symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user).

```
// src/Repository/UserRepository.php
namespace App\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

I hope this was helpful